# Photos crashing when uploading print order

Tags: photos, printing

I'm trying to order a 100 page hardcover book through the Photos app on macOS 10.12.1. I have placed all my photos, go to complete my order, but the Photos app repeatedly crashes at around 85% upload.

Some points:

- Creating a PDF preview works fine, and everything appears fine.
- I have individually gone into every photo to ensure it is downloaded from iCloud.
- I have tried starting Photos while holding Shift to clear the cache.
- I have tried starting in safe boot.

Here is the crash report (all the reports are identical).

```
Crashed Thread:        3

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000018c24f51bec0 Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11 Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x18c24f51bec0:
    Memory Tag 249         0000000281033000-00000002897f2000 [135.7M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> 
    MALLOC_NANO            0000600000000000-0000600004c00000 [ 76.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Application Specific Information: objc_msgSend() selector name: bytes Photo Foundation logging:   2016-11-29 21:57:55.889: Volume: RDVolume(0x600001a69b80) modelId=1 uuid=NFJYV07mTS6MCzjIdd55PQ optimisticLock=0 tableName=RKVolume state=persisted: name: Macintosh HD diskUuid: 1A548BF5-C18E-36DD-9764-2B16F5188C6C isOnline: Yes doesn't have a bookmark (__58-[RDVolumeCache internalFindVolumeByBookmarkForVolumeURL:]_block_invoke:445) 2016-11-29 21:57:55.900: Volume: RDVolume(0x600001a6a440) modelId=2 uuid=QbAlfsnQTn+vxeWDXzlAUw optimisticLock=0 tableName=RKVolume state=persisted: name: Macintosh HD diskUuid: 1A548BF5-C18E-36DD-9764-2B16F5188C6C isOnline: Yes doesn't have a bookmark (__58-[RDVolumeCache internalFindVolumeByBookmarkForVolumeURL:]_block_invoke:445) 2016-11-29 21:57:56.247: Volume: RDVolume(0x600001a69b80) modelId=1 uuid=NFJYV07mTS6MCzjIdd55PQ optimisticLock=0 tableName=RKVolume state=persisted: name: Macintosh HD diskUuid: 1A548BF5-C18E-36DD-9764-2B16F5188C6C isOnline: Yes doesn't have a bookmark (__58-[RDVolumeCache internalFindVolumeByBookmarkForVolumeURL:]_block_invoke:445) 2016-11-29 21:57:56.247: Volume: RDVolume(0x600001a6a440) modelId=2 uuid=QbAlfsnQTn+vxeWDXzlAUw optimisticLock=0 tableName=RKVolume state=persisted: name: Macintosh HD diskUuid: 1A548BF5-C18E-36DD-9764-2B16F5188C6C isOnline: Yes doesn't have a bookmark (__58-[RDVolumeCache internalFindVolumeByBookmarkForVolumeURL:]_block_invoke:445) 2016-11-29 21:57:56.297: Volume: RDVolume(0x600001a69b80) modelId=1 uuid=NFJYV07mTS6MCzjIdd55PQ optimisticLock=0 tableName=RKVolume state=persisted: name: Macintosh HD diskUuid: 1A548BF5-C18E-36DD-9764-2B16F5188C6C isOnline: Yes doesn't have a bookmark (__58-[RDVolumeCache internalFindVolumeByBookmarkForVolumeURL:]_block_invoke:445) 2016-11-29 21:57:56.297: Volume: RDVolume(0x600001a6a440) modelId=2 uuid=QbAlfsnQTn+vxeWDXzlAUw optimisticLock=0 tableName=RKVolume state=persisted: name: Macintosh HD diskUuid: 1A548BF5-C18E-36DD-9764-2B16F5188C6C isOnline: Yes doesn't have a bookmark (__58-[RDVolumeCache internalFindVolumeByBookmarkForVolumeURL:]_block_invoke:445) 2016-11-29 21:58:08.267: *** Assertion failure in
-[RDVersion(RedRockProperties) orientation], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/PhotoApp/PhotoApp-451.20.9/lib/redrock/Database/Models/RKVersion+Properties.m:42 Message: bad orientation: 0 on RDVersion(0x608002297200) modelId=52 uuid=byw16ok6TU2l82zA0bg13Q optimisticLock=0 tableName=RKVersion state=persisted,readonly Backtrace: 0   PhotoFoundation                0x00007fff9f4bd4e8 -[PFAssertionHandler newAssertionInfoInMethod:object:function:file:lineNumber:description:arguments:]
+ 370 1   PhotoFoundation                     0x00007fff9f4bd677 -[PFAssertionHandler continueAfterAssertInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:arguments:]
+ 111 2   PhotoFoundation                     0x00007fff9f4bd330 _PFAssertContinueHandler + 308 3   RedRock                             0x0000000107ba97a0 -[RDVersion(RedRockProperties) orientation] + 99 4  PAImaging                           0x0000000107407590
-[PAImageRequestService previewSizeForVersion:orientation:] + 134 5   PAImaging                           0x0000000107404e98
-[PAImageRequestService submitPreviewRequest:canceler:] + 1035 6   PAImagingCore                       0x0000000107979210
-[PAPreviewRequest submitSynchronous:] + 80 7   Photos                              0x00000001052766da __63-[IPXSidebarViewController newPosterImageForAlbum:longestEdge:]_block_invoke + 405 8   PhotoFoundation                     0x00007fff9f491c95
-[PFDispatchQueue _invoke:] + 73 9   PhotoFoundation                     0x00007fff9f49a680 __54-[_PFFastLimitedConcurrencyQueue dispatchGroup:async:]_block_invoke_2 + 35 10  libdispatch.dylib        0x00007fffa449bf5f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12 11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffa4493128
_dispatch_client_callout + 8 12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffa44a8c71 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 630 13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffa449fea3
_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 734 14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffa4494ee0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 476 15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffa4494cb7
_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 99 (-[RDVersion(RedRockProperties) orientation]:42) 2016-11-29 21:58:08.750: *** Assertion failure in
__75-[LiImmutableModelCore initWithModelId:table:properties:defaultProperties:]_block_invoke_2, /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/PhotoApp_SubFrameworks/PhotoApp-451.20.9/lib/lithium/Common/Table/LiImmutableModelCore.mm:128 Message: fileName(404) already added Backtrace: 0   PhotoFoundation    0x00007fff9f4bd4e8 -[PFAssertionHandler newAssertionInfoInMethod:object:function:file:lineNumber:description:arguments:]
+ 370 1   PhotoFoundation                     0x00007fff9f4bd677 -[PFAssertionHandler continueAfterAssertInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:arguments:]
+ 111 2   PhotoFoundation                     0x00007fff9f4bd330 _PFAssertContinueHandler + 308 3   PhotoLibraryPrivate                 0x00007fff9f836b6f __75-[LiImmutableModelCore initWithModelId:table:properties:defaultProperties:]_block_invoke_2 + 193 4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f404e12
__53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 114 5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f404ccf -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 239 6   PhotoLibraryPrivate                 0x00007fff9f836845
__75-[LiImmutableModelCore initWithModelId:table:properties:defaultProperties:]_block_invoke + 222 7   PhotoLibraryPrivate                 0x00007fff9f857afd
-[LiTable modelPropertyIndexMapForSignature:createMap:] + 132 8   PhotoLibraryPrivate                 0x00007fff9f836564
-[LiImmutableModelCore initWithModelId:table:properties:defaultProperties:] + 798 9   PhotoLibraryPrivate                 0x00007fff9f82acb5
__100-[LiClientTable bufferReaderWithPropertyPaths:readOnly:defaultLocalModelProperties:coreLoadedBlock:]_block_invoke
+ 189 10  PhotoLibraryPrivate                 0x00007fff9f861247 -[LiRequest handleLoadReply:] + 138 11  PhotoLibraryPrivate                 0x00007fff9f57cdfd __36-[LiRequest handleReply:forLibrary:]_block_invoke + 77 12  PhotoFoundation         0x00007fff9f491c95 -[PFDispatchQueue _invoke:] + 73 13  PhotoFoundation                     0x00007fff9f49903e
__48-[_PFFastLimitedConcurrencyQueue dispatchAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 35 14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffa449bf5f
_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12 15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffa4493128 _dispatch_client_callout + 8 16  libdispatch.dylib  0x00007fffa44a8c10 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 533 17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffa449fea3
_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 734 18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffa4494ee0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 476 19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffa4494cb7
_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 99 (__75-[LiImmutableModelCore initWithModelId:table:properties:defaultProperties:]_block_invoke_2:128) 2016-11-29 21:58:09.447: -[PAPreviewMaker
_renderVersionToSize:description:canceler:canceled:timedOut:] Error: Failed to render preview image, version = IMG_3675.JPG, RDVersion(0x600001a8f730) modelId=21785 uuid=89knAHUMRDSKl1hNCvNrpg optimisticLock=0 tableName=RKVersion state=persisted, result = 0, error = Error Domain=PAImagingErrorDomain Code=1019 "(null)" UserInfo={English Error String - Not Localized=client should check for master availability before trying to export; perhaps prompting to reconnect} (-[PAPreviewMaker
_renderVersionToSize:description:canceler:canceled:timedOut:]:508)
```

This really stumps me. Any ideas of what else I can try? I've contacted Apple but we are yet to find a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

This was acknowledged as a bug in macOS Sierra by AppleCare. It appears to have been fixed in the latest macOS 10.12.2 beta.